# Opencv Access Webcam Inside a Docker Container as an Unprivileged User

Tags: python-3.x, linux, docker, opencv

I'm running a docker container inside a linux host. I have a slight problem accessing my webcam as an unprivileged user within my ubuntu-20 docker container.

Code below is what I use for testing my webcam:

```
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    retval, image = video.read()
    cv2.imshow("test", image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  somename:
    privileged: true
    container_name: somename
    image: somename-img
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - "..:/home/someuser/somename"
      - "/tmp:/tmp"

    # extra settings for X11 linux users
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
    devices:
      - "/dev/video0:/dev/video0"
      - "/dev/video1:/dev/video1"
    network_mode: host
    ipc: host
```

I've placed myself into the video group, and yet when running the above code, I get the warning `[ WARN:0@0.087] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (876) open VIDEOIO(V4L2): can't find camera device`, essentially giving a bogus image to feed imshow and crash. The issue here is that I am not running as root inside the container. It works perfectly fine as root, but I wish to run it not as root.

Comment: If you need the host network, host display, host filesystem, host users, host devices, and privileged mode are you gaining anything by running this application in a container?

Comment: Pardon me, I was trying everything there is to make it work. But fyi yes, the main reason why docker is chosen is because portability and packaging aspect. Isolation is an added benefit.